# How to add object in object?

Tags: javascript

I have object JS as: `var a =  {'name' : 'value'};`

I tried to add this in another object:

```
var obj = {};

obj = a;
```

It works. But I want to make the following objects model:

```
var obj = { 'localKey' : {{'key1' : 'v'}, {'key2', 'w'}} }
```

How to add object into `var obj` correct?

So, I need to extract data value by complicated code:

```
localKey.key1
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Object.assign()`. BTW can you please elaborate it a bit?

Comment: Do you want a list of objects stored in `obj`?

Comment: I updated question, see again please

Comment: I think you want to add objects to an array (`[{ name: 'v'  } , { name: 'w' }]`), if you want to add it to an object, you have to provide a key. (`{ a: { name: 'v'  } , b: { name: 'w' }}`)

Comment: No, I need: `{ 'localKey' : {{'key1' : 'v'}, {'key2', 'w'}} }`

Comment: `{{'key1' : 'v'}, {'key2', 'w'}}` is not a thing. It's not possible.

Comment: So, I can not reach deep value by specifying some keys?

Comment: Sure you can `var obj = { a: { name: 'v' } , b: { name: 'w' }}` and then `obj.a`.

Comment: You can have `{'key1': 'v', 'key2': 'w'}` or you can have `[{'key1': 'v'}, {'key2': 'w'}]`, you can't have `{{'key1' : 'v'}, {'key2', 'w'}}`.

Comment: Something like:
obj.localkey1 = {'key1': 'v'};
obj.localkey2 = {'key2','w'};

Comment: It can be `{localKey: {key1: "v", key2: "w"}} or {localKey:[{key1: "v"},{key2:"w"}]}` or `{localKey:{a: {key1: "v"}, b:{key2:"w"}}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var obj = { 'localKey' : {'key1' : 'v', 'key2', 'w'}}
```

now you can do

```
obj.localJey.key1 //'v'
```

Comment: How to add another object ` {'key1' : 'v', 'key2', 'w'}` to key 'localKey'?

Comment: if you want to have multiple  `{'key1' : 'v', 'key2', 'w'}` in localKey than use array like `var obj = { 'localKey' : [{'key1' : 'v', 'key2', 'w'}, {'key1' : 'v', 'key2', 'w'}]}`
and access it like `obj.localJey[0].key1` and `obj.localJey[1].key1`

Comment: @OPV is this what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

see the snippet. I've demonstrated how can you append object inside object as well as inside array.

```js
var obj= {};

var arr = [];

var obj2 = {
  'name' : 'abc'
}
var obj3 = {
'name' : 'def'
}
obj = {a : obj2, b : obj3};

console.log(obj);

arr.push(obj2);
arr.push(obj3);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj1={"first":"first","second":2}
var obj2={"first":"first2","second":22}
obj1.newObjAdded=obj2; //Adding obj2 to obj1
```

**Result is:**

```
{
first:"first",
newObjAdded:{first: "first2", second: 22},
second:2
}
```